# Como determinar intervalos para um requisição?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Bom dia, galera!
Tenho o seguinte cenário: estou consumindo uma API do Google que me retorna dados de um determinado canal do Youtube, basicamente eu faço a requisição e o retorno é uma lista de URLs de vídeos. Só que a API tem uma cota de 10000 requisições por dia, e essa aplicação receberá muito mais que isso diariamente, pois se trata de um anúncio publicitário dinâmico.

Queria saber se tem como determinar que seja feita apenas uma requisição por dia. Exemplo: Faço uma requisição hoje, guardo os valores dentro de uma variável ou objeto, e no dia seguinte faço uma nova requisição para atualizar a lista de URLs.

O código que tenho é esse:

```
let json = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${apiKey}&channelId=${userId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=${getMax}`;

$.getJSON(json, function(response){

    for (var i = 0; i < response['videoId'].length; i++){
        var videoId = response['videoId'][i];
        let urlVideo = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;
        const newElement = document.createElement('iframe');
          newElement.setAttribute('src', urlVideo);

          mySiema.append(newElement);
        }   
});
```

Comment: Você não pode armazenar os dados recebidos num banco de dados e verificar se naquele dia já foi feita uma requisição?

Comment: Na verdade eu não queria envolver banco de dados nessa aplicação. Teria como fazer essa mesma verificação com Javascript?

Comment: Partindo-se do pressuposto que você vai precisar armazenar essa informação em algum lugar, só consigo pensar em cookies ou local storage. Claro que não irá funcionar caso o usuário limpe os cookies ou acesse de um navegador diferente, mas talvez se ajuste no seu cenário.

Comment: Você quer que faça essa entrega quando o cliente voltar a sua página ou você quer que fique instalado no browser como se fosse um deamom? Se for o primeiro caso um cookie resolve ou web push convidando os clientes registrados a página. No segundo caso não tem como é uma questão de segurança e efemeridade dos dados no navegador.

Comment: A solução do cookie me parece ser uma boa, porém como eu iria barrar a requisição?
No caso, como informar que só deve ser feita outra requisição em 24h?

Comment: Acredito que seria apenas salvar o dia em que você fez a requisição no cookie. Antes de fazer a requisição, você verifica se o último dia da requisição foi hoje. Se for, você não faz a requisição.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, de verdade. Vou tentar solucionar esse problema dessa forma

Comment: Coloca um timer para só quando der o intervalo desejado, executar a requisição novamente.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta para ficar algo mais visível. Se for útil, você pode aceita-la clicando no check que fica na esquerda da resposta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, você precisa armazenar os dados em algum lugar, de forma que você não precise realizar a requisição novamente.

Como você não deseja utilizar banco de dados, a única forma que vejo seria utilizando cookies ou local storage (que eu recomendo, inclusive, você pode ler mais sobre ele nesse link da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)).

Uma lógica que você pode seguir é a de salvar no local storage, juntamente com os dados dos vídeos, a data em que você fez a última requisição. Antes de fazer qualquer requisição, você obtém esses dados e verifica se já fez a requisição hoje. Dessa forma, você vai fazer apenas uma requisição diária.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, a cada usuário uma requisição seria feita, correto?
Estou tentando uma solução para fazer uma requisição diária, e para qualquer usuário que banner for exibido ele não fará uma nova requisição. Não sei se consegui me fazer claro

Comment: Você quer dizer usuários diferentes em máquinas diferentes? Aí a solução acima não irá funcionar mesmo. Acredito que só envolvendo banco de dados para conseguir salvar as informações e ter acesso em diferentes acessos.